# Insert text in a form control of type input text

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to insert a text in an input text from code? I have a form which has to contain current values and then user will edit those values he diseres. There is a getter to read the actual value but what about setting one?

Comment: What does the getter look like?

Comment: well something like FormControlName.value

Comment: Read about 2 way binding, somewhere there https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: @StephaneM Thank you

Comment: If you have a FromControl reference then you should be able to do `formControl.setValue('something')`  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @E.Sundin Great,thank you

Comment: Please find the below mentioned answer, hope it will help

Comment: @E.Sundin What about if  I have input type of date and time? It doesn't work only by passing the string, shall I convert it to a date?

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer to below solution and modify your code**

HTML Code

```
<form *ngIf="formObject" [formGroup]="demoForm" (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="address" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="address2" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="city" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control" formControlName="state">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
        <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
        <option value="karnataka">Karnataka</option>
        <option value="gujrat">Gujrat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="zip" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Typescript Code..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive-form',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactive-form.component.css']
})
export class ReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {
  demoForm: FormGroup;

  formObject = {
    email: 'email@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
    address: 'address 1 here',
    address2: 'address 2 here',
    city: 'pune',
    state: 'maharashtra',
    zip: '412411'
  };  

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.createDemoForm(this.formObject);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  createDemoForm(formObj) {
    this.demoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [formObj.email, Validators.required],
      password: [formObj.password, Validators.required],
      address: [formObj.address, Validators.required],
      address2: [formObj.address2, Validators.required],
      city: [formObj.city, Validators.required],
      state: [formObj.state, Validators.required],
      zip: [formObj.zip, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(){

  }

}
```

Please don't forget to import FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in App.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you want to be able to be able to change the value of a variable from both the input and your Typescript, you can do this with two way binding. NG Model allows you to do this.

I suggest checking out this section in the Angular Tour of Heros tutorial.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#two-way-binding